# Need to make sidebar responsive only when screen width is greater than 1024px

Tags: css, sidebar, responsive

I'm new to WordPress and I want to make my sidebar responsive when the screen width is greater than 1024px. currently, the sidebar becomes responsive when the screen width is greater than 768px.

The website in concern is https://worklifeandmoney.com

I want to achieve this through additional CSS. I'm using the NewsUp theme.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Update:** I tried to make it work with flex but couldn't succeed.

```
/* sidebar responsiveness */
@media (min-width: 1024px)
.col-md-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean “make my sidebar responsive”?

Comment: Search online for media queries and you'll see that you should have more braces in your code for a start

Comment: @JacobPeattie when you inspect and slide the inspect window to change the width of the website, you'll see the sidebar width is changed based on width.